# Recommendations for requesting quotes?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, contact

I have a tab in the header having named `Request Quote`. In my experience I have not yet used a quote functionality. Please provide me any help or any link that will be helpful for me.

Is there is any plugin or something else?
I need your ideas and suggestions.
I shall be very thankful to you all.

Answer (score 3):

There are a good few form building plugins out there but the best by far is [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/)

Well worth the license fee and you can offset that cost when you bill your client. They will be able to create as many forms as they need then and attach them as widgets in a sidebar or in a blog post or on a standard wordpress page.

In your case you need to see what the form should look like or at least what fields it needs and then you can create the 'Request a Quote' page and attach your form to it.

Comment: Thanks for reply but its not free

Comment: I know but you didn't specify free plugins and it really is worth paying for if a simple contact form won't do everything you need. You can use it on future projects too so any form you need to create will be quick & easy to do. It'll save yourself and your clients time & money in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Grunion Contact Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/grunion-contact-form/), it is developed by Automattic for .com but also released as .org plugin. It got major update recently.

Answer (score 1):

I am a big fan of Contact Form 7, contactform7.com, a free plugin. There are add-on modules that can store form submissions in a database.